# How to run this query in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

My doc has an array field **Keys**

**Keys1** and **Keys2** are two arrays

I want all the docs where **Keys** contains any value in **Keys1** ***AND*** any value in **Keys2**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no great way to represent this query yet (as of 1.1.2) - if you ask on the list or file a feature request we can try to get something cooked up.

For now the best bet is probably to use an $in query to do half of the work:

`db.test.find({keys: {$in: Keys1}})`

You can do this in combination with a $where which can do the Keys2 part (but won't take advantage of an index - that's why it is good to do as much as possible with the regular query syntax). This would look something like this:

`db.test.find({keys: {$in: Keys1}, $where: "for (i in this.keys) { for (j in Keys2) { if (this.keys[i] == Keys2[j]) return true;}} return false;"})`

**In latest versions of mongodb 2.6+ you can do this by $and operator.**

```
db.test.find({$and:[{keys: {$in: Keys1}},{keys: {$in: Keys2}}]})
```